# What is the different between AWS Elasticsearch and AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-redshift

I read the document that both for data analysis and in cluster structure but I don't understand what use case different.

**Amazon Elasticsearch** is a popular open-source search and analytics engine for use cases such as log analytics, real-time application monitoring, and clickstream analytics.[Amazon Elasticsearch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-elasticsearch-service.html)

**Amazon Redshift** is a fully managed, petabyte-scale data warehouse service in the cloud. You can start with just a few hundred gigabytes of data and scale to a petabyte or more. [Amazon Redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/welcome.html)

Comment: Amazon Elasticsearch, Amazon Redshift AWS Elastic and AWS Elastic MapReduce are cluster and used for data analysis.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Amazon Redshift** is a hosted data warehouse product, while **Amazon Elasticsearch** is a hosted [ElasticSearch](http://www.elastic.co) cluster.
Redshift is based on PostgreSQL and (afaik) mostly used for BI purpuses and other compute-intensive jobs, the Amazon Elasticsearch is an out-of-the-box ElasticSearch managed cluster (which you cannot use to run SQL queries, since ES is a NoSQL database).

Both Amazon Redshift and Amazon ES are managed services, which means you don't need to do anything in order to manage your servers (this is what you pay for).  Using the AWS Console you can add new cluster and you don't need to run any commands on order to install any software - you just need to choose which server to run your cluster on (number of nodes, disk, ram, etc).

If you are not familiar with [ElasticSearch](http://www.elastic.co) you should check their website.

---

Edit: It is now possible to write SQL queries on ElasticSearch: [SQL Support for AWS ElasticSearch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/sql-support.html)

Comment: Do you mean that Redshift and ElasticSearch both provide BI and for manage purpose  ,but different in it can query or not?

Comment: I think the answer is outdated now since we can write SQL type queries on ES now: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/sql-support.html

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan thanks for your comment, feel free to update the answer with the latest data (please don't change the answer, just add more info to it).

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @IMSoP's assertions above...

To compare the two is like comparing an elephant and a tiger - you're not really asking the right question quite yet.

What you should really be asking is - what are my requirements for my use cases to best fulfill my stakeholder / customer needs, first, and then which data storage technology best aligns with my requirements second...

To be clear - Whether speaking of AWS ElasticSearch Service, or FOSS / Enterprise ElasticSearch (which have signifficant differences, between, even) - ElasticSearch is NOT a Relational Database (RDBMS), nor is it quite a NoSQL (Document Store) Database, either...

ElasticSearch is a Search Engine / Index. It does some things very well, for very specific use cases, however unlike RDBMS data models most signifficantly, ElasticSearch or NoSQL are not going to provide you with FULL ACID Compliance, or Transactional Statement Processing, so if your use case prioritizes data integrity, constrainability, reliability, audit ability, regulatory compliance, recover ability (to Point in Time, even), and normalization of data model for performance and least repetition of data while providing deep cardinality and enforcing model constraints for optimal integrity, "NoSQL and Elastic are not the Droids you're looking for..." and you should be implementing a RDBMS solution. As already mentioned, the AWS Redshift Service is based on PostgreSQL - which is one of the most popular OpenSource RDBMS flavors out there, just offered by AWS as a fully managed solution / service for their customers.

Elastic falls between RDBMS and NoSQL categories, as it is a Search Engine / Index that works most optimally with "single index" type use cases, where A LOT of content is indexed all at once and those documents aren't updated very frequently after the initial bulk indexing,but perhaps the most important thing I could stress is that in my experience it typically does not scale very cost effectively (even managed cluster services) if you want your clusters to perform well, not degrade over time, retain large historical datasets, and remain highly available for your consumers - and for most will likely become cost PROHIBITIVE VERY fast. That said, Elastic Search DOES still have very optimal use cases, so is always worth evaluating against your unique requirements - just keep scalability and cost in mind while doing so.

Lastly let's call NoSQL what it is, a Document Store that stores collections of documents (most often in JSON format) and while they also do indexing, offer some semblance of an Authentication and Authorization model, provide CRUD operability (or even SQL support nowadays, which makes the career Enterprise Data Engineer in me giggle, that SQL is now the preferred means of querying data from their NoSQL instances! :D )- Still NOT a traditional database, likely won't provide you with much control over your data's integrity - BUT that is precisely what "NoSQL" Document Stores were designed to work best for - UNSTRUCTURED DATA - where you may not always know what your data model is going to look like from the start, or your use case prioritizes data model flexibility over enforcing data integrity in general (non mission critical data). Last - while most modern NoSQL Document Stores may have SOME features that appear on the surface to resemble RDBMS, I am not aware of ANY in that category at current that could claim to offer all that a relational database does, with Oracle MySQL's DocumentStore being probably the best of both worlds in my opinion (and not just because I've worked with it every day for the last decade, either...).

So - I hope Developers with similar questions come across this thread, and after reading are much better informed to make the most optimal design decisions for their use cases - because if we're all being honest with ourselves - everything we do in our profession is about data - either generating it, transporting it, rendering it, transforming it....it all starts and ends with data, and making the most optimal data storage decisions for your applications will literally define the rest of your project!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This strikes me as like asking "What is the difference between apples and oranges? I've heard they're both types of fruit."

AWS has [an overview of the analytics products they offer](https://aws.amazon.com/big-data/datalakes-and-analytics/), which at the time of writing lists 21 different services. They also have [a list of database products](https://aws.amazon.com/products/databases/) which includes Redshift and 10 others. There's no particularly obvious reason why these two should be compared, and the others on both pages ignored.

There is inevitably a lot of overlap between the capabilities of these tools, so there is no way to write an exhaustive list of use cases for each. Their strengths and weaknesses, and the other tools they integrate easily with, will change over time, and some differences are a matter of "taste" or "style".

Regarding the two picked out in the question:

- Elasticsearch is a product built by [elastic.co](https://www.elastic.co), which AWS can manage the installation and configuration for. As its name suggests, its core functionality is based around search - it can be used to build a flexible but fast product search for an e-commerce site, for instance. It's also commonly used along with other tools to search and aggregate logs and monitoring data.
- Redshift is a database system built by AWS, based on PostgreSQL but optimised for extremely large data sets. It is designed for "data warehouse" applications, where you want to write complex logical queries against the data, like "how many people in each city bought both a toothbrush and toothpaste, this year compared to last year".

Rather than trying to make an abstract comparison of all the different services available, it makes more sense to start from the use case which you actually have, and see which tool best fits that need.